# Run useEffect only on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this functional component -

```js
    function ModelPredict({ model }) {
    const [predictionDate, setPredictionDate] = useState('')
    const [predictionValue, setPredictionValue] = useState('')
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPrediction = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true)
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/predict/${model.id}/?`
                              + new URLSearchParams({pred_date: predictionDate}))
            const predictionValue = await res.json()
            setPredictionValue(predictionValue)
            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        if (predictionDate) fetchPrediction()
    }, [predictionDate, model])

    return (
        <div>
            <label>Select Prediction date: </label>
            <input type="date" name="date" value={predictionDate}
             onInput={e => setPredictionDate(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            {isLoading && <p>Predicting ...</p>}
            {!isLoading && predictionValue && <p>Prediction: {predictionValue.prediction}</p>}
        </div >
    )
}
```

Currently `useEffect` will fire every time on date input.
I want that the `useEffect` should run only when the submit button is clicked.

One way to do it would be to have another state `inpReady` and calling `setInpReady(true)` inside onSubmit and then check inside useEffect if `inpReady` is true before calling `fetchPrediction`.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Or you could just create a function that you call on submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm understanding your question, but what's the need for useEffect here? what's the problem with removing all the code from useEffect and putting it all inside your onSubmit function? that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be setting a `isSubmmited` flag and use it as a dependency in the useEffect:

```
const [isSubmmited, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false)
```

And then onSubmit to call `setIsSubmmited(true)`

Another option is simply to let the onSubmit handle the logic you want in the `useEffect`